# What is the difference between "a park" and "the park"

Tags: difference, articles, singular

What is the difference between "a park" and "the park". Except the fact that we use "a" when we mention a park in the first time and then we need "the" when we need to say that we are talking about **that** park.
For example we tell about our trip to another city and we tell:

> We went to a bar. I went to the park.

I have found that it is possible to use "the park" and "a park" even if we mention a park in the first time. So why do we use "the"?  Is it correct to use two sentences together with mentioning for the first time but using "a" and "the" (as in the example above).

Comment: Hmmm, lots of people mentioning the "first mention - a, second mention - the" as if it were a grammar rule recently.  Is there something going around?

Comment: Also  see the answers to this question: [The indefinite article when we mention something for the first time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77292/) and StoneyB's answer here: [Why are different articles used before the same words?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/)

Comment: @JamesK I don't know, the first/second mention thing is not a bad rule of thumb (e.g. I saw **a** man walking down the street; **The** man was wearing **a** green hat) it's just that it's far from a complete description of article usage. (e.g., **the** street in the first sentence!)

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule that you use "a" on the first mention and "the" on the second mention.

You use "the" when you have established a definite identity for the noun. You use "the" when there is a shared understanding between you and the listener that can answer the question "which?".

Now when you say "I went to the park" you mean that you know that your listener knows *which* park you are talking about.  That is probably because you and your listener are in the same town and there is only one nearby local park.

But there are several bars you could visit, so you might say "I went to a bar" because you know that your listener doesn't know which bar.

Now suppose there are several parks in the city that you are visiting. If your listener doesn't know which park you mean then you would say "I went to a park".

Similarly, suppose you always go to the same bar on Friday evening, and your listener knows that. You might say "I went to the bar"

Now one way to establish the identity of a place is to mention it.

> I went to a bar on Friday. The bar was clean.

By the time you reach the second sentence, your listener knows which bar - It is the bar you mentioned in the first sentence.  But the reason for using "the" is **not** because it is mentioned a second time.  It is because the listener knows which bar you are talking about.

Comment: In New York City, I believe 'the park' usually means Central Park.

Comment: But in London there are several, however if you live in Penge, then "the park" is Crystal Palace Park, etc.

Comment: We also have the usage "I went to the pub" when the hearer does *not* know (or even necessarily need to know) which pub the speaker went to. It's understood in the same way as "I went to church". The specific location is not important -- the information being that the speaker spent his time drinking in (presumably) convivial company.

Comment: That is the institutional use of "the".  In Britain "the pub" is an institution in a way that bars are not in the US of A.

Comment: @JamesK - yes. I grew up opposite Brockwell Park, but if I went to see a pal in Dulwich or Camberwell, I might say we went to 'the park' meaning Dulwich or Ruskin parks respectively, and I would be understood to mean 'the nearest park'.

Comment: @PrimeMover - likewise the cinema or the theatre (theater).